# How to prevent execute query reload the page. I tried preventDefault(); it worked but it prevent php from execution

Tags: php, html, mysql

```js
var add = (function () {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

function clickCounter(){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = add();
}
```

I am trying to make a counter onclick. on each click add the final result to data base.
it works when I use button type submit, but it reloads the page and back to 0, and if I make the button type button the quire will not work.

```html
<button class="button" id="result" name="submit" onclick="clickCounter()" type="button"  >0</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I highly recommend reading [ask] in order to understand what should be included in a question. Right now we have no information we could use to help you (code, errors, logic descriptions...). Read the linked article and all it's linked resources in the text, then [edit] your question with the necessary information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Ajax calls, it would help